# Is it OK to use regression when analysing a difference of variables?

Tags: regression

Consider an experiment where we want to check if the change in a variable X between 2 time periods (X1 at t=1, X2 at t=2) is caused by independent variable A or B (which do not change over time).

Would the following analysis make sense: a regression where DX = X2 - X1 is the dependent variable and A & B are the independent variables? Or can you not take the regression of a difference of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that could make sense.  But you are making more assumptions that if you treat X1 as a baseline variable and fit a model like Y ~ X1 + B.  This allows the slope of X1 on Y to be something other than 1.0, which happens when you have measurement error or regression to the mean.  More about this is in the transformation and change chapter of [BBR](http://fharrell.com/doc/bbr.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [panel data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data) to think about other possibilities.

If A and B are constants, $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$ will be zero too, and constants in your model will not help you.

There are methods for analysis of time change, like [first difference estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-difference_estimator) or [fixed effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_effects_model), but them will not help you if you hope to find causality in a model made only by constants as independent variables.

First [difference estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-difference_estimator) will clear your mind:

> The estimator is obtained by running a pooled OLS estimation for a
>   regression of $\Delta y_{it}$ on $\Delta x_{it}$ [...]

Doing that eliminates changes that are constant from any $t-1$ to $t$

In your example, the variables probably will be not even correlated... so you have to model your experiment differently.